# iOS enterprise distribution - GPS issue

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, app-store, ios-enterprise

I have developed an app for my organizations employee and distributing it using apple enterprise program account.

Now in this app there is a functionality to get GPS data of that device. Its working perfectly on the debug build but when I make a release build using the enterprise certificate its not working. Even its not asking for the GPS permission.

info.plist file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
        <string>English</string>
        <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
        <string>Neptune</string>
        <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
        <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
        <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
        <dict/>
        <key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
        <dict/>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.neptune.neptunetimesheets</string>
        <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
        <string>6.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleName</key>
        <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
        <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
        <string>APPL</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>2.0.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
        <string>????</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>2.0.0</string>
        <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
        <string/>
        <key>NSMainNibFile~ipad</key>
        <string/>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
        <array>
          <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
          <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        </array>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
        <array>
          <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
          <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        </array>
        <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
        <string>[App Name] would like to access your location when running and displayed.</string>
        <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
        <string>[App Name] would like to access your location when running and displayed.</string>
        <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
          <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
          <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>UIInterfaceOrientation</key>
        <array>
          <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        </array>
        <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
        <string>CDVLaunchScreen</string>
      </dict>
    </plist>
```

Comment: You should show your `info.plist` file and tried code. So people can help you.

Comment: @MahendraGP added my info.plist file.